# Google Analytics Measurement Protocol Only Custom Dimensions and Metrics did not collected

Tags: c#, google-analytics

I try to collect application usage data through Google Analytics.

My application is written in C# Winform.

I write custom Google Tracker Moudle using HTTP GET/POST protocol (RestSharp). I followed [Measurement Protocol](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/parameters) document. Also I set data definition of Custom Dimensions and Custom Metircs on my Google Analytics.

My Google Tracker send this to Google Analytics,

```
https://www.google-analytics.com/collect?v=1&tid=UA-12345678-91&cid=aaaaaaa-aaaaa-aaaaa-aaaaa-aaaaaaa&ua=Windows%2b10%2bHome&sr=96x96&vp=2560x1440&ul=ko-KR&an=app&av=0.0.0&t=event&ec=AppUsability&ea=SetAutoRun&el=TurnOn
```

it worked! and I can see event on The REPORT.

Problem is **Custom Dimensions & Metrics** does not shows up at CUSTOM REPORT.
It shows me only *There is no data*

```
https://www.google-analytics.com/collect?v=1&tid=UA-12345678-12&cid=aaaaaaa-aaa-aaa-aaa&ua=Windows%2b10%2bHome&sr=96x96&vp=2560x1440&ul=ko-KR&an=application&av=0.0.0&t=event&ec=PrinterUsage&ea=PrintMemo&el=ButtonClick&cd1=aaaaaa-aaaaa-aaaaa&cd2=283&cd3=283&cd4=Top&cm1=0&cm2=0&cm3=1
```

Only **cd1=aaaa-aaaaaa-aaaaa&cd2=283&cd3=283&cd4=Top&cm1=0&cm2=0&cm3=1** part data is missing at Custom Report.

What should I do here?

Comment: Did you remember to create the dimensions and metrics in the property settings (custom definitions) ? Also it might take some time before they show up (i.e. if you set them as secondary dimension or use them is custom reports, they don't show up in standard reports), so maybe you simply haven't waited long enough.

Comment: @EikePierstorff Really? I did set custom defintions, but I did not expected to wait more than a week...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Eike Pierstorff 's comment was right. I wait it for **two weeks** and finally Google Analytics' custom fields and dimensions are updated. So... Make sure create custom dimensions and metrics in the property settings and wait it for updating more than **weeks**.